# Powershell - Import list of paths from Text/CSV, Get-ACL then export to Text/CSV

Tags: powershell, csv, import, export

Good Afternoon

I'm fairly new to Powershell so please forgive my ignorance.

I am attempting to run Get-ACL on a list of server paths in a text document so I can get a list of AD accounts/groups with permissions and what level of permissions for each folder path. I then need it to export this info into a CSV or Text file. I've run through a large amount of scripts on here and tried to tweak them to fit my specific needs but I'm still having trouble. I'm currently trying to tweak this one but I'm not sure where I am going wrong;

```
$FullList = Get-Content "C:\ShareList.txt"

$DataOutFile = "C:\PermissionInformation.txt"

Foreach ($Folder in $FullList)
{
    $ACLs = get-acl $Folder | ForEach-Object { $_.Access }

    Foreach ($ACL in $ACLs)
    {
        $DataOutInfo = $Folder.FullName + ":" + $ACL.IdentityReference
        Add-Content -Value $DataOutInfo -Path $DataOutFile
    }
}
```

The source list "ShareList.txt" is formatted as follows;

```
\\phttest\Testing$\Test1
\\phttest\Testing$\Test2
\\phttest\Testing$\Test3
```

The script runs and doesn't appear to error out, however nothing is entered when I check the output file, its completely empty.

I've also tried a much more simple variant that uses CSV's;

Source file is ShareList.csv

```
Folder,
\\phttest\Testing$\Test1
\\phttest\Testing$\Test2
\\phttest\Testing$\Test3
```

Script;

```
$FilePath = "C:\ShareList.csv"
$List = Import-CSV $FilePath
foreach($Folder in $List)
{
Get-ACL $Folder | ForEach-Object
}
```

I get the following message: 
cmdlet ForEach-Object at command pipeline position 2
Supply values for the following parameters:
Process[0]:

I've been trying to Frankenstein a working script but so far it appears that I'm going round in circles, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Sam

Answer (score 0):

Try this, also omit the comma after the word "Folder" in the CSV header:

```
$FilePath = "C:\ShareList.csv"
$List = Import-CSV $FilePath
foreach($Folder in $List.Folder)
{
Do something for each folder.
}
```

**Update**

Based on your comment, here's the next guess.  Try this:

```
$FilePath = "C:\ShareList.csv"
$List = Import-CSV $FilePath
foreach($Folder in $List.Folder)
{
$acls = $Folder.Access
foreach($acl in $Acls)
    {
    $acl
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for responding, I've tried what you said, using the following;

Comment: Thanks very much for responding, I've tried what you said, using the following and it seems to be bringing back what I need; I'm not sure if I have it exactly right but I'm a huge amount further along than I was.    
     
    $FilePath = "C:\ShareList.csv"
    $List = Import-CSV $FilePath
    foreach($Folder in $List.Folder)
    {
    Get-ACL $Folder
    }

Thank you greatly for the assistance